# Multi line invert grep match using file

Tags: bash

I am trying to visualise all new sockets created after a save point in Debian Linux 5.14:

```
ss -a > state
ss -a | grep -v -f state
```

Expected output : Nothing

Observed output : The same as ss -a

I checked the content of the file and every line does properly end with a $ indicating it's multine.

Can't truely grasp why this happens, did anyone encounter this before ?

Comment: please update the question with corresponding samples from `state` and the 2nd `ss -a` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `-F` so the lines are treated as fixed strings and not regexes. This ensures that items like `*` and `[::ffff:127.0.0.1]` are not treated as wildcards and character classes.
- For good measure, use `-x` to match whole lines.

```
$ ss -a > state
$ wc -l < state
1867
$ ss -a | grep -vxFf state | wc -l
56
```